# Repeat pattern using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to be able to validate the strings below to allow data between backticks unlimited times as long as it is followed by a comma, if it is not a comma must be a ")". Whitespaces are allowed only out of the backticks not in them.

I am not experienced with regex so I dont know how to allow a repeated pattern. Below is my pattern so far.

Thanks

**UPDATED**

```
// first 3 lines should match
$lines[] = "(`a-z0-9_-`,`a-z0-9_-`,`a-z0-9_-`,`a-z0-9_-`)";
$lines[] = "( `a-z0-9_-`, `a-z0-9_-` ,`a-z0-9_-` , `a-z0-9_-` )";
$lines[] = "(`a-z0-9_-`, 
    `a-z0-9_-` 
    ,`a-z0-9_-` ,`a-z0-9_-`)";

// these lines below should not match
$lines[] = "(`a-z0-9_-``a-z0-9_-`,`a-z0-9_-`,`a-z0-9_-`)";
$lines[] = "(`a-z0-9_-``a-z0-9_-`,`a-z0-9_-`.`a-z0-9_-`";

$pattern = '/~^\(\s*(?:[a-z0-9_-]+\s*,?\s*)+\)$~/';

$result = array();

foreach($lines as $key => $line)
{
        if (preg_match($pattern, $line))
        {
            $result[$key] = 'Found match.';
        }
        else
        {
            $result[$key] = 'Not found a match.';
        }
}

print("<pre>" . print_r($result, true). "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you weren't very clear about the matching rules for the data between the brackets, and you didn't really specify if you wanted to capture anything so...I took a best guess based on context of your code, hopefully this will suit your needs.

**edit**: fixed code block so it would show the backtics in the pattern, also changed the delimiter from ~ to / since OP was confused about that

```
$pattern = '/^\((\s*`[a-z0-9_-]+`\s*[,)])+$/';
```

Comment: I have updated my code in my post, sorry about that it was a bit ambiguous. This does not find a match for any of the lines. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, I had used SO's inline code brackets which are back-tics so they didn't show up properly in my pattern. I changed to their other form so you should see it how.  Also in my pattern I use tilde ~ as the pattern delimiter, and I see in your code update that you added forward slashes.  So you need to either remove the outer forward slashes or else those tildes

Comment: I went ahead and edited my pattern to use / instead of ~ so it shows exactly what you should have since you got confused by delimiters

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me works a treat works great. I was not aware ~ was a delimiter.

Comment: Whats exactly is the difference between using / and ~ as delimiter, what is best to use. Examples I see use / never come across ~ until now.

Comment: You can use pretty much any non-alphanumeric character as a delimeter.  The main thing to consider is that if you need to match for whatever you choose, you have to escape it in your regex.  I personally use ~ because it stands out more and you rarely ever have to escape it.  As opposed to / which having to escape it comes up more often, especially if you are scraping html content.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. It looks like you want this:

```
$pattern = "~^\(\s*`[a-z0-9_-]+`\s*(?:,\s*`[a-z0-9_-]+`\s*)*\)$~";
```

The two problems with your regex were:

1. You had two sets of delimiters (slashes and tildes) - pick just one and stick with it. My personal preference is parentheses because then you don't have to escape anything "just because delimiters", but also it helps me remember that the entire match is the first entry in the match array.
2. By making the comma optional, you were allowing things you didn't want. The solution does involve repeating yourself a little, but it is more accurate.

Comment: your pattern is missing matching for backtics, I suspect SO ate them same as in my pattern! Also, you don't actually need to repeat the sub-pattern like that.

Answer (score 0):

here is a generic repeat pattern:

```
preg_match_all("/start_string([^repeat_string].*?)end_string/si", $input, $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: What question are answering?